# extjs desktop - how to hide a window when it is created?

Tags: extjs, window, hide, desktop

I am storing values of extjs desktop window in a database.

Case:

When user minimized a window and logs out,
the window should stay minimized when he logs in again.

Now on logon the before minimized window pops up

The values are all there! But I cant find the property to set...

I tried `hidden:true`, but no effect.

Comment: Are you executing `.show()` on instatiation of the app? If so you need to test whether this should be the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a property to set when creating the window for extjs-desktop. But a superior function is invoking creation, takes window as response and does "win.show()". At this point i am checking the "minimized" value delivered by AJAX.